What is this bias called?
People often transfer money from their savings to their checking account when their checking balance drops below a certain amount, for example, 1000 dollars. Let's say you plot the checking account balance at which people make this transfer, you find that the most common value is 999, with a progressive decline in frequency down to a 0 balance. For someone trying to understand the likelihood that a transfer will be made at a particular bank balance, they would need to know how often people check their bank balance (i.e., how often they are 'exposed' to the bank balance value). Otherwise, based purely on frequency, it might seem that more people prefer to transfer at 999 than at 99, even though this simply reflects the fact that people don't let their account balance get to 99 and transfer before then.
I want to find out the name of this bias, which could give this faulty impression if the number of exposures is not accounted for. The things I came across when I looked it up are 'survival bias' and 'left truncation'

It's not really bias, though is it? Or are you trying to infer from checking account balances the balance of both checking and savings accounts?

I am not sure it is a bias, though it is equivalent to a well-known phenomenon such as that described at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101264/distribution-at-first-time-a-sum-reaches-a-threshold (though your example involves subtraction rather than addition).  You might call it something like "the distribution of the excess when crossing a threshold".

Bias refers to the difference between an estimator and a random variable's true expected value. If you are using the actual transfer balance statistics to estimate the desired transfer balance parameters, this will result in significant bias; however, in your case, I would try to differentiate between the two different random variables (desired vs. actual), and then there is no need to discuss bias at all (since you are estimating 'actual', not 'desired', balance at transfer). In other words, do not make any kind of inference for 'desired' based on the 'actual' data, except to say that 'desired' will be larger than 'actual'.
If you actually want to estimate desired, I would consider modeling this as a hierarchical distribution. Let $W$ be the transfer value that can be modeled as a gamma random variable and $X$ be the checking frequency that can be modeled as an exponential variable, potentially one that is conditional on the balance if you feel people would be checking more if they had a lower balance. Furthermore you would want to model transaction frequency and amount as two random variables $Y$ and $Z$, perhaps as exponential and lognormal random variables, respectively.
$$W\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$$
$$X|W\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda_1(W))$$
$$Y\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda_2)$$
$$Z\sim\text{Lognormal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
Using a model like this can help in estimating the desired transfer balance distribution.
